# MOBILE checkout page for PayPal Add to Cart button and variable dollar amount Buy Now button?

Tags: mobile, paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get two particular button types to take MOBILE PHONE users to a mobile version of the payment page. I have PayPal Payments Standard:
~ Add to Cart
~ Buy Now without a dollar amount (customer enters it themself to pay a bill)

The buttons generated in my account lead to the payment screen where the user has to enter all their data but it's MUCH too TINY on a mobile phone.  How does it get to be mobile responsive? Is it a special code, or is there some other way to do it that isn't overly complicated?

Would appreciate some help. I have done hours of research to try to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally PayPal payment page (the page payers see when they click the button) does detect mobile devices automatically and display mobile style. I happened to be testing a buy now button today and it worked fine. Please check the source code the button uses.

If ok please post here the code and how to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How old is your PayPal account? 

The rep told me all accounts will be integrated for mobile eventually (they're doing it in batches), but they have no idea how long it could take for mine. Months? Years? The guy couldn't say. I asked if a brand new account would be different and he said he wasn't sure. So if yours is relatively new, I'm wondering if that might be why it works properly. I'm jealous!

Comment: It's not about how old the PayPal accounts are. I think what you and PayPal phone service talked about was misleading. You were probably talking about the new checkout experience they are pushing out at the moment (not 100% online yet, only available to some regions, which the phone call was right about), which looks blueish, not the yellowish old one. The new one is adaptive to both desktop and mobile, and it looks nicer. It's not determined by how old your account is, but where you are, where the buyers are, and it's not 100% available so sometimes it will still show the old one.

Comment: However, the old one is also compatible with mobile in a different way: it outputs the mobile style if it detects the devices, it's just not adaptive design. So I think your question here would be, why doesn't my current PayPal payment style display as mobile? And the answer could be related to the source code of your button.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, I appreciate your taking the time to offer information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I want to share to help anyone else who's struggling with this issue. *As mentioned earlier, I have an old PayPal account.*

I had a special phone appointment with PayPal's development team and discovered:

1. **There are no add to cart buttons that lead to mobile checkout in PayPal Payments Standard accounts.** For this I would have to get Mobile Express Checkout, which the PayPal rep himself said is complicated to integrate (I checked and it really is) OR get PayPal Payments Pro for $30 per month. I don't want to do either or those.
2. **There is no way to get a $0 (no set dollar amount) button to lead to mobile checkout** because any time the customer has to enter data such as an amount, quantity, etc, that invalidates the mobile compatibility. It is called an "Unsupported Use Case": https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/

My only button solution is to use individual Buy Now buttons with set amounts, because there is a mobile payment page for those. But I won't make my customers pay for one thing at a time, that's incredibly annoying and unprofessional.

So I've decided to just go with a third party shopping cart for my website like PrestaShop, OpenCart, or even WordPress with WooCommerce. They won't cost me anything because I'll install them on my hosting account. (If I had under 10 products I would use the free Ecwid option, but I have too many.)

It has been a long journey!